# filter method in Javascript isn't work. But the other filter methods are working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filter

My program crashes when I want to add a filter function for the item status column. What I don't understand about this is that the filter function worked optimally for all other columns and when I did it for the "Article status" column in exactly the same way as for the other columns, the filter function no longer works. As I said before, I don't understand why this could be because I did it exactly the same as for the other columns. My json-Arrays:[enter image description here][1]

My error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: artikelstatus.includes is not a function
    at searchAllTable (artikelSuche.js:124)
    at filterByAll (artikelSuche.js:108)
    at getValueFromArtikelstatus (artikelSuche.js:162)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (artikelSuche.html:29)
```

```js
function searchAllTable(artikelnummerValue, materialbezeichnung1Value, materialbezeichnung2Value, teileartValue, materialklasseValue, artikelstatusValue, data) {
  var filteredData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    materialbezeichnung1Value = materialbezeichnung1Value.toLowerCase();
    var materialbezeichnung1 = data[i].materialbezeichnung1.toLowerCase();
    materialbezeichnung2Value = materialbezeichnung2Value.toLowerCase();
    var materialbezeichnung2 = data[i].materialbezeichnung2.toLowerCase();
    var artikelnummer = data[i].artikelnummer;
    var teileart = data[i].teileart;
    var materialklasse = data[i].materialklasse;
    var artikelstatus = data[i].artikelstatus;

    if (materialbezeichnung1.includes(materialbezeichnung1Value) && artikelnummer.includes(artikelnummerValue) && materialbezeichnung2.includes(materialbezeichnung2Value) && teileart.includes(teileartValue) &&
      materialklasse.includes(materialklasseValue) && artikelstatus.includes(artikelstatusValue)) {
      filteredData.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return filteredData;
}
```

Comment: [java to javascript is like ham to hamster](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do read the [tour] and [ask].  You might also like to read [mcve].  There's a *lot* of code there and it looks like only one or two lines are relevant to the question - if you can narrow this done to *just* the relevant parts than demonstrate your issue, you'll likely get a quick response.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you for the review. Know I have edit my code :)

Comment: Given it works for other columns, it's not an issue with [includes](https://caniuse.com/?search=includes) itself.  You might like to check the **data type** of `artikelstatus` within that function as it's likely not a string/array *at that time*, ie you get the same error with `var x = 123; x.includes("1")`

Comment: @freedomn-m 
I did the same with my json array "alleMaterialklassen" and it worked there

Comment: @freedomn-m you are right, I have eddit my code and make a screen from my logs. you can look it at the end. artikelstatusValue is a String and artikelstatus a int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet is based on an assumption all records are String type

```
if (materialbezeichnung1.includes(materialbezeichnung1Value) && artikelnummer.includes(artikelnummerValue) && materialbezeichnung2.includes(materialbezeichnung2Value) && teileart.includes(teileartValue) &&
  materialklasse.includes(materialklasseValue) && artikelstatus.includes(artikelstatusValue)) {
  filteredData.push(data[i]);
}
```

If you're relying on a String function, then force the value type to String using `String(var)`

```
if (String(materialbezeichnung1).includes(materialbezeichnung1Value) && String(artikelnummer).includes(artikelnummerValue) && String(materialbezeichnung2).includes(materialbezeichnung2Value) && String(teileart).includes(teileartValue) &&
  String(materialklasse).includes(materialklasseValue) && String(artikelstatus).includes(artikelstatusValue)) {
  filteredData.push(data[i]);
}
```